# How to format the received JSON to make it look beautiful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

I get an array of objects and display it on the screen, but the data is not beautiful, how to format to have indents and everything was beautiful, tell me how to do this using js or some kind of library.

```js
const express = require('express');
const Database = require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    db.pictures().then(data => {
        const pictures = JSON.parse(data);
        res.send(pictures)
    })
});
```

**How it looks on the screen:** 
[image]

Comment: there are some extension available for chrome use it. for ex: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en

Comment: JSONView is also a good alternative

Comment: Where's this 'on the screen'? Is it how it appears in browser window?

Comment: @estus yes, this is screen in browser window

Comment: See suggestions above. Or use network tab to examine a response.

Comment: Umm... set the `content-type` to `aplication/json` and let the browser handle formatting for you?

Comment: If it's supposed to be consumed by a client-side API, it's concerning that you care how it looks. Remove all the whitespace from the formatting and conserve bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(pictures, null, 4);    // stringify with 4 spaces at each level
```

Taken from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/indent-json-javascript)

Either format from backend or from client side using JSON.stringify

JSON.stringify takes more [optional arguments.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters)

I recommend formaingt it in client side, as you can use the original JSON for rendering the page.

Answer (score 2):

**Human readable**

Actually I am not sure why would we display data in Json format to the user, But it's your requirement, so i will roll with it.

There are useful answers and comments that gives you what you want, to display the json well formatted on the screen.

This answer intends to add bit of an edge if you want to display the json data in **actual human readable form** in an easy way. You can use this if you find necessary.

[json.human.js](http://marianoguerra.github.io/json.human.js/src/json.human.js)

It takes json input and gives you a structured data as output. Example below:

[image]

[image]

[Source](http://marianoguerra.github.io/json.human.js/)

Answer (score -2):

you can use JsonLint to beautify your json 
https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: OP is asking for javascript code not an external website